# Docker build fails with "RUN: command not found"

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I am running below contents in dockerfile it runs until yum installation and fails as, /bin/sh: RUN: command not found

DockerFile:

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest
ADD . /tmp/
RUN yum install gzip -y && \
    yum install tar -y && \
    yum install libstdc++.so.6 -y && \
RUN cd /tmp && /usr/bin/gunzip TeradataToolsAndUtilitiesBase__linux_indep.16.20.10.00.tar.gz && /usr/bin/tar -xvf TeradataToolsAndUtilitiesBase__linux_indep.16.20.10.00.tar 
RUN cd /tmp/TeradataToolsAndUtilitiesBase/ && ./setup.bat a
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Error:

```
Installed:
  libstdc++.i686 0:7.3.1-5.amzn2.0.2                                            

Dependency Installed:
  glibc.i686 0:2.26-32.amzn2.0.1         libgcc.i686 0:7.3.1-5.amzn2.0.2        

Complete!
/bin/sh: RUN: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install gzip -y &&     yum install tar -y &&     yum install libstdc++.so.6 -y && RUN cd /tmp && /usr/bin/gunzip TeradataToolsAndUtilitiesBase__linux_indep.16.20.10.00.tar.gz && /usr/bin/tar -xvf TeradataToolsAndUtilitiesBase__linux_indep.16.20.10.00.tar' returned a non-zero code: 127
system:ttudockerimg$
```

Please help.

Comment: `RUN cd /tmp` is taken as part of the previous `RUN` command, because the line before it ends with a backslash.

Comment: Remove the trailing backslash on the 3rd line of the first RUN command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use one **RUN** command, and escape newlines. If you have several commands, you have to wrap them in a bash command.

Besides that, you can extract from a `.tar.gz` file directly without uncompressing it first.

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest 
ADD . /tmp/ 
RUN yum install gzip -y && \ 
    yum install tar -y && \ 
    yum install libstdc++.so.6 -y && \
    /bin/bash -c 'cd /tmp && \
    /usr/bin/tar -xzvf TeradataToolsAndUtilitiesBase__linux_indep.16.20.10.00.tar.gz && \
    cd /tmp/TeradataToolsAndUtilitiesBase/ && \
    ./setup.bat a 
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```